# Adding Swing Validation

Tags: java, swing, validation, user-interface

I'm trying to add some validation to my Java Swing Application. I have a number of `JCheckBoxes`, at least one must be checked to proceed to the next screen otherwise a dialog is shown. The next button takes the user to the proceeding page. My question is how to I implement validation on `JCheckBoxes`.

My GUI swing app: http://postimg.org/image/dvpyfxavt/

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My question is how to I implement validation on jcheck boxes.

Comment: If the boxes arnt ticked a dialog should appear.

Comment: Swing is event-driven, when do you want this? When a button is pressed?

Comment: When the next button is clicked...

Answer (score 3):

### You Could

You could use an `ActionListener` to each `JCheckBox` and change the state of the `JButton` based on the number of `JCheckBox`'s that are selected.

Take a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Basically, this `ActionListener` would be a shared instance between your `JCheckBox`s with sole purpose of determining how many are actually selected.  To make this easier, I would either create an array or `List` and add all the `JCheckBox`s to it.  This way you could simply iterate the list of check boxes until you found a selected one...

### You Could...

Use an `InputVerifier` to verifier the state of your check boxes when they lose focus.  For more information see [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification).

The only problem(s) with this approach is...

1. You can only have a single verifier per component.  Yes, you could write a verifiers that did multiple jobs, but that is the problem, a verifier should do just one job.
2. The component has to loose focus before the validation process takes place.  This might not seem like a big deal, but if the user is sitting there, "I've checked all the buttons, why is the button not enabled", they might not realise that they have to change the focus context in order to for the validation to occur...

Comment: @nachokk This is just another approach. I like real time feedback, I hate hitting "next" and seeing "You didn't do such and such" errors...looking at you web forms >|

Comment: That's true, but `InputVerifier` in that case is also a good choice.

Comment: @nachokk <face plant> - Why do I always thing `InputVerfier` is only used on text components :P

Answer (score 2):

You have to add an event listener to your button, more pricesly an `ActionListener` if you want to go more far, you can use `Action` interface  that behaves like a controller of the button with useful constants&methods.

Example with ActionListener:

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
            // make validations here, if validation not passed
            // show the dialog you can use -->
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error happen!");
            //else you have to switch to another view
        }

})
```

More information with better examples: [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

---

The next is completely personal, when i have to validate a form when a button is pressed i want to separate validation logic in another class. I make my custom interface that defines a `validate()` method

```
public interface FieldValidator{
 final String MY_VALIDATOR = "myValidator";
 void validate() throws ValidationException
 //Note: ValidationException is a custom exception
}
```

And in the `JComponent` i want to validate for example a textfield i define my custom validator.

```
textfield.putClientProperty(FieldValidator.VALIDATOR, new FieldValidator(){
             @Override
            public void validate() throws ValidationException{
                if(textfield.getText().isEmpty())
                       throw new ValidationException("text is empty");
            }

});
```

A concrete-class that holds all the JComponents in the form.

public MyValidator implements FieldValidator{
   private final JComponent[] components;

```
public MyValidator(JComponent ... components){
   this.components=components;
}

@Override
public void validate() throws ValidationException{
    for(JComponent component : components){
        ((FieldValidator)component.getClientProperty(VALIDATOR)).validate();
    }
}
```

}

And then in client code

```
 FieldValidator fieldsValidator = new MyValidator(checkbox1,checkbox2,textfield);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
               try{
                    fieldsValidator.validate();
                    //all it's ok change the view
                }catch(ValidationException ex){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error happen");// error happen
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate the advice, when you say //make validations here, if something bad. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: When validation not pass